# Image upload to other server

Tags: php, image-uploading

Having this problem:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('ftp.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, username, password);

ssh2_scp_send($connection, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], '/path/to/dir/1.jpg', 0644);
```

The dir chmod is set on 0777 but no image is uploaded. Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see what error do you have

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /home/prosoccerdata/apps/test/admin/paginas/personeel/add/upload.php on line 8 but in my phpinfo I have this : libSSH Version libssh2/1.2.6